# PDFA generated with pdfathesis is 20 times as big as the normal PDF

Tags: xetex, tikz-pic, memory, pdf-a

I was happy to being able to create a PDFA document of my dissertation by means of the pdfathesis package. However, my dissertation in PDF format uses 3MB while the PDFA file is 85.3MB big. I found out that every tikzpicture of a matrix multiples the amount of used space in PDFA format. I made a minimal example in Overleaf:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/bpfxhqhywzbg

You need to download the project, compile locally (with XeLaTex) such that you get the main.sh and main.gs files. Then open a terminal, go in the PDFA_Matrix folder and type `sh main.sh`.

I used the lipsum package because it makes a difference. Without the lipsum text the normal PDF has a size of 50KB and the generated PDFA 250KB. With the lipsum text, the 50KB PDF is converted to a 1,2MB big PDFA.

A simple solution is to externalise the plots but maybe someone is also curious and wants to know why it happens.

Comment: You could make some small example files for (combinations of) these features, using PDF/A or regular PDF, to investigate the size increase. With such a big difference (28x) it should be visible for smaller files as well. If it isn't then it's more likely that something else in the thesis is responsible, you could cut content gradually until you find the problem.

Comment: Apparently, tikz or pgfplots are an issue. Compiling the first chapter without its one and only graphic (a tikzpicture with a colored matrix of nodes) reduces the PDFA size for the first chapter from 17MB to 300KB. I could externalize all plots but that will be a lot of work. If anyone has a better solution, I would appreciate it!

Comment: If you want a solution, you should make an small example that can be used for tests (including all needed files and description of the compilation steps needed to reproduce the problem).

Comment: I edited the question according to the new information and added a link to a MWE.

Comment: Overleaf is not the best place for a MWE. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8402/adding-an-overleaf-link-as-well-instead-of-mwe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is using ghostscript with the -dPDFA option to create a pdf/A-1 compliant pdf. Your example is also using opacity. But transparent objects and layers are forbidden in PDF/A-1 and it looks as if ghostscript is doing a *lot* work to remove them. I couldn't check what exactly happens as even with small examples the uncompressed pdf is *huge*.

This example create a 9kb pdf:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red,opacity=0.3](0,0)rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Converting it with (I'm on windows)

```
gswin64 -dPDFA=1  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -o main-PDFA.pdf main.pdf
```

gives an 160kb pdf, so more 10 times larger, and uncompressing it one gets 142000 kb.

So your options are

- remove all the opacity settings or
- convert to pdf/A-2 by using -dPDFA=2 where transparency is allowed. At least with my ghostscript this gives reasonable sizes.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit to solve the mystery, but when I use -dPDFA=2 then I get the error 'GPL Ghostscript 9.23: Setting Overprint Mode to 1
 not permitted in PDF/A-2, reverting to normal PDF output'.

Comment: are you using the colorspace package?

Comment: I used everything exactly as stated in your MWE, so no.

Comment: However, removing opacity works! So thank you, I'm going for that!

Comment: My example doesn't set the overprint mode and I don't get such a message with it, but I have newer ghostscript.